# Using Insert Into Select while converting values to match a third table

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert-into

I don't know how to simply phrase my question, but here is the scenario.  I have two tables with data as follows:

CertStatus Table:

```
CertStatus_KEY  CertStatus_ID
1               ACTIVE
2               EXPIRED
```

CertImport Table:

```
Status
ACTIVE
EXPIRED
EXPIRED
ACTIVE
EXPIRED
ACTIVE
```

What I need to do is take the CertImport.Status column, convert all of those statuses to the CertStatus_KEY that matches the CertStatus_ID, and then copy all of that info into a third table with two columns, so the data would end up as follows.

Certification Table:

```
Certification_KEY   CertStatus_KEY
1                   1
2                   2
3                   2
4                   1
5                   2
6                   1
```

I'm trying to use an Insert Into Select statement but I get an error that says the Subquery returned more than 1 value.  Here's what I've got:

```
INSERT INTO Certification (CertStatus_KEY)
SELECT (
    SELECT CertStatus_KEY from CertStatus where CertStatus_ID in (
        SELECT Status from CertImport)
    )
```

Simplified, the goal is to convert the CertImport.Status to the CertStatus.CertStatus_KEY value that corresponds to the matching CertStatus.CertStatus_ID, and then insert that value into Certification.CertStatus_KEY.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  You want `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Insert into Certification (CertStatus_Key)
select cs.Certstatus_Key
from CertStatus cs
inner join CertImport ci on cs.CertStatus_Id = ci.Status;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=52e4733b493ad3cd7d1699e5fec905d6)

Note: In SQL server, it is not guaranteed in which order the results would return from the select unless an order by clause is specified (or at least there is a clustered index). For a small data set like this you would get the result just as you asked but for a larger one there is no guarantee. Actually, design seems to be bad from the start, CertImport should have an ID column?

Comment: I didn't understand question well. But it seems he need two columns in certification table.

Comment: @nitzien, I got that as Certification_Key is primary key auto generated (Certification_Key int identity). That results in two columns just as he asked.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, The Certification_KEY is just automatically incrementing, just as the CertStatus_KEY does in the CertStatus table.  Thanks!